# Get value | Redis | Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I have these keys-values:

```
field:first:code = test1 
field:second:code = test2
```

How can i get "first" by "test1" and "second" by "test2"?

Comment: You'll need to add more info on what types of objects `field` and `first`, etc. are. Please add a reproducible example that someone else could run.

Comment: @D Malan It looks like: **field:first:code**

Comment: @DMalan I corrected the description